# I need Fiat -> BTC merchant service

Tags: buy-bitcoins, sell-bitcoins, btce, merchants, merchant-services

Hello bitcoin community.

I'm running startup and we think how to accept payments. Our customers are far not geeks and they don't know what BTC is. However, I'd prefer to collect BTC on may wallet, not fiat. I've solved all tax issues in my country and I can deliver invoices to my customer where we will use fiat currency they paid in. But I'm looking for some merchant service that automatically turns fiat they pay through Visa/SWIFT or probably even PayPal into BTC using actual exchange rate. Could anyone suggest something?

Answer (score 4):

There used to be a service by coinvoice.com that did exactly what you're asking. Unfortunately, they're no longer operating. I've heard bitpagos.com does that for Latin America. Otherwise, you're looking at setting up something with coinbase or bitpay to transfer fiat right away for bitcoins.

Best of luck with your business!

Answer (score 2):

Your question might be out of context here (in 3 years, how many people will be interested in an answer, given that things change so fast in this space?).

Having said that, it **all depends where you're at**.  Some, but not all, exchanges will let deposits flow into your account if you properly explain to them the nature of your business, why do you want bitcoin in the first place, etc.  They will load you with questions, and if you have a shell corp in which nobody can see through it, they'll probably deny you to have fiat coming in from others than you.

If you cannot use bitpay or similar to get bitcoin, given your demographics, your best bet may be to receive the fiat and then send it to an exchange and convert.

What is very interesting about your question is that it *might* show to people a business opportunity there.

Comment: -1 Why would the question be out of context here? "Some exchanges will let deposits flow in[...]" Which exchanges allow this service? Please focus on answering the question instead of speculating about potential problems and the implications of the question being asked.

Comment: There are couple of reasons for me to collect Bitcoin. First of all - I'm from the country where corruption is that high, that purchasing the car for USD 10K I should pay USD20K with different taxes and they all will be stolen by corruptioners. Not even a penny will be used by goverment as it should be. I'm too tired because of that for over 20 years I'm in business. My lawyers and accountants have found that since bitcoin is not considered `monies` - we should not pay any taxes when earn it. I'll be paying only when I'm converting BTC->fiat to pay salary and other expense here.

Answer (score 0):

A feature request for this purpose was created for BTCPay in July 2019

- https://github.com/btcpayserver/btcpayserver/issues/923

It looks like this may be possible with some extensions if you run your own BTCPay server.