# Is there a way to accept fiat currencies online without having a credit card and having the fiat automatically converted to Bitcoin?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, sell-bitcoins, merchant-services

Is there a way to accept fiat currencies online without having a credit card and having the fiat automatically converted to Bitcoin?

I know services such as BitPay and so on let's you accept Bitcoin payments on your site but what if you want to do the opposite thing and accept Fiat currencies and have them automatically converted to Bitcoin and sent to your account? Preferably without too much sign up hassle from the merchant's side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need Fiat -> BTC merchant service](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41191/5406)

Comment: Well there has still not been a lot of answers : )

Comment: Yeah, also your question puts it much nicer. :)

Comment: Thanks : ) I normally try to find clear and useful ways of expressing my questions and statements if I can.